# Python: for loop stops at first row when reading from csv

Tags: python, for-loop, gis, mapbox, arcgis

With this code, I can get it to fire thru the first row in a csv and post the content. Without the for loop, it works great as well. I am also, using a simple print statement, able to print out all of the rows in the csv. Where I'm getting stuck is how to get this to loop thru my csv (2300 rows) and replace two inline variable. I've tried a couple of iterations of this, moving statements around, etc, this is my latest attempt.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import arcrest
import json
import csv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "uid"
    password = "pwd"
    portalId = "id"
    url = "http://www.arcgis.com/"
    thumbnail_url = ""
with open('TILES.csv') as csvfile:
    inputFile = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    x = 0 # counter to display file count
    for row in inputFile:
        if x == 0:
            map_json = {
  "operationalLayers": [
    {
      "templateUrl": "https://{subDomain}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/abc.GRSM_"+row['ID']+"_pink/{level}/{col}/{row}.png?access_token=pk.secret",
      "id": "GRSM_SPECIES_OBSERVATIONS_MAXENT_5733",
      "type": "WebTiledLayer",
      "layerType": "WebTiledLayer",
      "title": row['Species']+" Prediction",
      "copyright": "GRSM",
      "fullExtent": {
        "xmin": -20037508.342787,
        "ymin": -20037508.34278,
        "xmax": 20037508.34278,
        "ymax": 20037508.342787,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 102100
        }
      },
      "subDomains": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
      ],
      "visibility": True,
      "opacity": 1
    }
  ],
  "baseMap": {
    "baseMapLayers": [
      {
        "id": "defaultBasemap",
        "layerType": "ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "opacity": 1,
        "visibility": True,
        "url": "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Topographic"
  },
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
    securityHandler = arcrest.AGOLTokenSecurityHandler(username,
                                                       password)
    #   Create the administration connection
    #
    admin = arcrest.manageorg.Administration(url, securityHandler)
    #   Access the content properties to add the item
    #
    content = admin.content
    #   Get the user    #
    user = content.users.user()
    #   Provide the item parameters
    #
    itemParams = arcrest.manageorg.ItemParameter()
    itemParams.title = "GRSM_"+row['Species']
    itemParams.thumbnailurl = ""
    itemParams.type = "Web Map"
    itemParams.snippet = "Maxent Output: "+row['Species']
    itemParams.licenseInfo = "License"
    itemParams.accessInformation = "Credits"
    itemParams.tags = "Maxent"+row['Species']
    itemParams.description = "This map depicts the tiled output of a Maxent model depicting the probability of occurrence of "+row['Species']+". An in-line legend is not available for this map. "
    itemParams.extent = "-84.1076,35.2814,-82.9795, 35.8366"

    #   Add the Web Map
    #
    print (user.addItem(itemParameters=itemParams,
                              overwrite=True,
                              text=json.dumps(row)))
    x = x + 1
```

Here's the csv:

```
Species,ID
Abacion_magnum,0000166
Abaeis_nicippe,0000169
Abagrotis_alternata,0000172
Abies_fraseri,0000214
Ablabesmyia_mallochi,0000223
Abrostola_ovalis,0000232
Acalypha_rhomboidea,0000253
Acanthostigma_filiforme,0000296
Acanthostigma_minutum,0000297
Acanthostigma_multiseptatum,0000298
Acentrella_ampla,0000314
Acer_negundo,0000330
Acer_pensylvanicum,0000333
Acer_rubrum_v_rubrum,0000337
Acer_rubrum_v_trilobum,0000338
Acer_saccharum,0000341
Acer_spicatum,0000343
```

Comment: Debugging questions should have a [mcve]. In this case it would be easier to figure out the problem if you could remove the code that is not relevant to the specific bug.

Comment: For now, change the x==0 to true. Since it only works for the first loop, my guess is that this if statement is preventing the rest of the rows from being processed.

Comment: Note: I would recommend you open your file as `with open('TILES.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:`

Comment: @Martin Evans, did that, thanks for tip (but didn't do much to getting me past this first iteration though).....

Comment: `securityHandler = arcrest.AGOLTokenSecurityHandler(username,
                                                       password)` is outside of your for-loop.  Did you intend that?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski no, and I was initially suspicious about that, but not quite sure on how to get it all wrapped into the same for-loop. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Try indenting the `securityHandler` line, and everything below it by 4 spaces. This will put it all inside your loop.

Comment: @Martin Evans Thanks, so this is a indention issue. When I do that, I get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. The JSON is throwing me off on figuring out where/when to indent, normally this is not such a big problem for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: The closing `}` probably needs indenting too.

Comment: Yeah, I've been moving that closing } around like a pinball to no effect. I'm wondering if this is even possible with that giant block of JSON followed by non-JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your indentation is wrong, you only have inside your `for` loop the `if` and the json:

```
 if x == 0:
      map_json = {
  "operationalLayers": [
    {
      "templateUrl": "https://{subDomain}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/abc.GRSM_"+row['ID']+"_pink/{level}/{col}/{row}.png?access_token=pk.secret",
      "id": "GRSM_SPECIES_OBSERVATIONS_MAXENT_5733",
      "type": "WebTiledLayer",
      "layerType": "WebTiledLayer",
      "title": row['Species']+" Prediction",
      "copyright": "GRSM",
      "fullExtent": {
        "xmin": -20037508.342787,
        "ymin": -20037508.34278,
        "xmax": 20037508.34278,
        "ymax": 20037508.342787,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 102100
        }
      },
      "subDomains": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
      ],
      "visibility": True,
      "opacity": 1
    }
  ],
  "baseMap": {
    "baseMapLayers": [
      {
        "id": "defaultBasemap",
        "layerType": "ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
        "opacity": 1,
        "visibility": True,
        "url": "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Topographic"
  },
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: Ultimately, it was a mind-crushing issue related to JSON formatting messing up indents, solved with notepad++ and find/replace tabs for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you might only be getting one row in your result is because you have the code contained in an if statement where the condition is x == 0. I can see you set x to be 0 outside the for loop and at the end of the loop you are incrementing x. This results in x no longer being equal to 0 and therefore your if statement condition is false.

Try removing the if statement completely and the increment line at the end. 
Just use:

```
for row in inputFile:
    # your code here
```

This will allow you to loop through the csv file

Comment: thanks for pointing that out...but no dice. Successfully fires thru one iteration still...removed   x = 0 # counter to display file count, if x == 0: and x = x + 1